# Generating dynamic .tabset in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

I wanna create 3 .tabsets, one per level of Species on the Iris Dataset (example).
On each .tabset, a want 3 or more tabs. Each tab will have your own plot.

I wrote this code:

````
```{r echo=FALSE, results='asis'}

library(tidyverse)

for(especies in levels(iris$Species)){ 
  cat('\n#', especies, '{.tabset}', '\n')
  cat('\n##',  'Petal Lengh x Sepal Length', '\n')
  iris %>%
    filter(
      Species == especies
    ) %>%
    ggplot(
      aes(
        x = Sepal.Length,
        y = Petal.Length
      )
    ) +
    geom_point() -> p
  print(p)
  cat('\n')
  cat('\n##', 'Sepal Length', '\n')
    iris %>%
    filter(
      Species == especies
    ) %>%
    ggplot(
      aes(
        x = Sepal.Length
      )
    ) +
    geom_histogram() -> p
  print(p)
  cat('\n')
  cat('\n##', 'Petal Length', '\n')
    iris %>%
    filter(
      Species == especies
    ) %>%
    ggplot(
      aes(
        x = Petal.Length
      )
    ) +
    geom_histogram() -> p
  print(p)
  }
```
````

I don't know why it isn't work. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

The stack keeps asking me for more details to post the question, so i have to write some more in order to be allowed to post.

Comment: Fala danilo blz, se você quer encadear gráficos no R da uma lida aqui https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/egg/vignettes/Ecosystem.html mas acho que isso resolver com  par(mfrow=c(3,3))

Comment: Fala, Bruno. Não quero fazer um grid de plots. Só dei um exemplos com o Iris dataset do que quero. Quero realmente gerar dinamicamente um .tabset para casa level de iris$Species.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things to get the desired result:

1) insert `{r, results = "asis"}` as chunk
2) add `cat('\n')` after the last `print`call

Comment: If i put `print(plotly::ggplotly(p))`, it doesn't work: the html widget is not printed. Do you know why or any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I think replaces your graphs pretty well

```
library(ggforce)


ggplot(iris) +
  aes(color = Species,fill = Species) +
  geom_autohistogram() +
  geom_autopoint() +
  geom_autodensity() +
  facet_matrix(vars(-Species), layer.diag = 1, layer.upper = 3, 
               grid.y.diag = FALSE)
```

Comment: Hey there. The graph is just for example purpose. Whats i want is to dynamically generate one .tabset per level of iris$Species, with plots in every tab.